# How to disable `q` key (quit) for *Geiser Debug* window?

Tags: key-bindings, window, major-mode, keymap

The `*Geiser Debug*` window disappears after pressing <kbd>q</kbd>. This is normally good for dismissing the error messages in the window (for scheme). However, I'd like to keep this window open so that I can see the output of evaluations. (And all too often, I inadvertently closed that window after an error.)

*Is there a way to disable the use of <kbd>q</kbd> key to close the `*Geiser Debug*` window (in `init.el`)?*

(This is with Emacs 28)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`C-h v major-mode` should tell you the name of the major mode for that buffer.

`C-h m` will tell you more about the mode, and it might tell you the name of the mode's keymap. If not, a good bet is that the name of the keymap is `THE-MODE-map`, where `THE-MODE` is the value of variable `major-mode`. (Maybe the map name is something like `geiser-mode-map`.)

Then just bind key `q` to whatever command you like in that keymap. (Binding it to command `ignore` makes it do nothing.)

```lisp
(define-key 'THE-MODE-map (kbd "q") 'ignore)
```